# What does % before a variable means

Tags: python

Hi I encounter these lines in a [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

# Install TensorFlow
try:
  # %tensorflow_version only exists in Colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass

import tensorflow as tf
```

But I do not understand this line:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
```

May I know what the modular sign is doing here? Thanks

Comment: It probably come from the import. `print type(%)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the magic command for selecting the 2.X TensorFlow version. It's available only in Google Colab.

Comment: `%` is not only available in Google Colab. Last I checked, my IPython console wasn't on Google Colab but I have magic methods: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html